# HP Pavilion DV7 laptop - screen went black after shutdown attempt, but it doesn't turn off

Tags: laptop, shutdown, hp-pavilion

Today I bought a used HP laptop computer, model HP Pavilion DV7-4120EM . At first everything worked ok. Then I used HP center software to search and install BIOS and driver updates. After it has finished installing, I wanted to turn the computer off and call it a day.

Computer screen then went black, but computer didn't turn off. The fan can still be heard, and little indicator lights on F11 and F12 are on ( they won't turn off if I click them, nor will Caps Lock light turn on ). I have pulled the power cord out in hope of computer running out of power. Trying to press or press and hold the power button doesn't have any effect. The bottom surface is warm, as if the laptop was being used normally. It's been in state like that for at least an hour now, and as I am writing this it still is. I just can't turn it off or do anything, the screen is black, and it is running ( or at least the fan is heard ).

What do you recommend me to do about it ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of removing the battery, placing it back in after a few seconds, and powering on the computer again?

Comment: @Applecot - I have thought about it. But isn't it risky, since the computer is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James, it's not risky to remove the battery while the computer is running. How about you shut it down? Next, take out the battery, wait atleast 15 minutes for everything to cool down. Next, put the battery back in. Now just because you hear the fan doesn't mean your PC is on - Not always.

---

I see you installed BIOS and driver updates. Above might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: I know my post was long and a bit messy, but I mentioned that using power button doesn't have any effect. Nor pressing it, nor holding it. Also, F11 and F12 lights are on. So you believe the BIOS update might have caused that problem, and just putting battery out and back could solve it ?

Comment: Pretty much. Try it! Also, what is your operating system?

Comment: I can give it a try, but for some reason my guts are telling me it's a bad idea. Although, it seems updating was also. It is Win 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Also if the F11 and F12 lights are one, means your PC is somewhere on. Try the battery removal process.

Comment: EH. Windows 7. This is of course going to happen. Windows 7 Ultimate always has BIOS problems. Check out this article : http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/28292-63-windows-bios-boot-problem

Comment: It says "If you update your BIOS you will have to boot into safe mode, first you should remove the battery" MICROSOFT.COM/WINDOWS-7-HELP

Comment: Excellent, it worked, thank you very much ! Do you recommend me to change the OS version to avoid this kind of problems in the future ?

Comment: Glad to help! You should use the latest operating system, so I'd say yes if this happens in the future, upgrade your OS!